# MS SQL - Fastest way to adding $2 to a varchar column with numbers

Tags: sql-server

Is there a faster way to do this directly in MS SQL ?

I also get an error saying: ***"Query-based update failed because the row to update could not be found. "***

```
    strQuery = "SELECT FEE from FEES_OlderImport"
    objRS.open strQuery

While not objRS.EOF
'// UPDATE EACH TABLE HERE
objRS("FEE")=objRS("FEE")+2
objRS.Update
    objRS.MoveNext
Wend
objRS.Close
```

THANKS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a faster way; since there's no reason that I can see to parse each individually, let the database update the entire set at one time.

```
Update fees_olderImport set fee=fee+2.0;
Update fees_olderIMport set fee = CAST(fee as DECIMAL(9,2))+2
```

though we may have to cast it back to character to make it work...

Relational databases operate very well on set data.  Taking the record set back to the server, then updating each record one at a time, not only adds a lot of network overhead, but is also a very inefficient use of set data.

On a design note:
Why is data being stored as text when you're wanting to do math on it?  As a rule of thumb, store values on which math may occur as numeric.  Other numbers may be stored as text, such as phone, ZIP codes, etc.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1.50' to data type int. The field is varchar and not an int,money,ect. can we somehow conver it just temp to do the calculations? THANKS

Comment: one hackish way is to make the 2 be 2.0.  Another would be to cast the fee field to a double.  The system is trying to implicitly convert based on the data type being added.  By making it 2.0 we show the engine we want to add a type double to begin with so it should handle the implicit conversion of fee to double.  But now we have a different problem... Are we sure all values of fee can be converted implicitly?  Or do we need to handle exceptions like $2.54 in the data?